# how to limit the numbers of product to show

Tags: shopify

I'm new to shopify. I'm trying to limit the output of the product for example 4 product for each tag. but seems like there is variables for me to loop..
anyone can help? thx.

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
          <li class="active">{{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}</li>
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ tag | link_to_add_tag: tag }}</li>
        {{ tag }}
        {% if collection.products.size > 0 %}
            <ul class="product-grid just">
            {% for product in collection.products %}
                {% if product.tags contains tag %}  
                    <li>{% include 'product-grid-item' %}</li>

                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p><strong><br/>No products found in this collection.</strong></p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`limit` parameter](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#for) can be used to display the first 4 products in a collection:

```
{% for product in collection.products limit:4 %}
```

However if you need to display a limited number of products with a given tag, you will need to implement your own counter. [See this discussion](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/getting-products-by-tags-when-in-a-collection-111353#comment-111518) on the Shopify forums for an example of how to do this.

E.g.

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
  {{ tag }}
  {% assign counter = 0 %}
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    {% if product.tags contains tag and counter < 4 %}
       <li>{% include 'product-grid-item' %}</li>
       {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a good separation the logic how many items are to be displayed is better put somewhere the "List" is made ready for output.

This way you don't have to do **content related** maths in the view, which is never a good idea since it doesn't put code where it belong and other people wanting to change something may have difficulties to find it. That being said you can either put the limitations on the collection.products object based on a configured backend parameter just before handing the object to the rendering or you go further back and intervene at the "grab products from database" point and limit/alter the result. ;)

There sure is a possibility to use an incrementing counter and stop at 4 in the template but I can hardly recommend to use that since it's not where the logic should be. The template should show, not think what to show, otherwise it's hardly reusable.

Comment: It's about information structure: 

Products, Productlists, Collection, etc - are parts of the shop content. 

It is **not** part of the view logic. It shouldn't be in the template.

Go to where the collection object is generated and alter the products to display there.

The template should not know what it displays, only how to display.